# .net DispatcherTimer fires tick event repeatedly

Tags: c#, .net, dispatchertimer

i have problem in my code that i don't even near to understand.

Here is my item interface;

```
internal interface IItem
{
    void Show();
    event EventHandler Completed;
    TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class ItemImage : IItem
{

    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler Completed;

    private DispatcherTimer _dt = new DispatcherTimer();

    public void Show()
    {

        _dt.Interval = this.Duration;
        _dt.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            _dt.Stop();
            Completed(this, new EventArgs());
        };
        _dt.Start();

    }
}
```

And here's my player:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int _pIndex = 0;
    List<IItem> list = new List<IItem>();

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        list = new List<IItem>()
        {
            new ItemImage() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Name = "Image1" },
            new ItemImage() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), Name = "Image2" },
            new ItemImage() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Name = "Image3" },
            new ItemImage() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7), Name = "Image4" }
        };
        Next();
    }

    void Next()
    {
        var tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = ((IItem)list[_pIndex]).Name;
        StackPanel1.Children.Add(tb);

        list[_pIndex].Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            Next();
        };
        list[_pIndex].Show();
        _pIndex++;
        _pIndex %= list.Count;

    }
}
```

First list plays with no problem but on second turn DispatcherTimer doesn't wait for my duration value, and immediately fires complete event. What do i do wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is happening (I didn't test it), but I see that every time you call `Show()`, another eventhandler is attached to the `Tick` in your `ItemImage` object. This could lead to some side effects you'll experiencing.

You might change it to:

```
internal class ItemImage : IItem 
{   

    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler Completed;

    private DispatcherTimer _dt = new DispatcherTimer();

    // constructor
    public ItemImage()
    {
        _dt.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            _dt.Stop();
            Completed(this, new EventArgs());
        };
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        _dt.Interval = this.Duration;
        _dt.Start();

    }
}
```

You could recreate the `DispatcherTimer` or move the event attaching to the constructor. (like above)

This is also done in the `Next()` method with `list[_pIndex].Completed`. (it attaches to a class member, so every buttonclick new handlers are added to the list.)

You might reconcider the style of attaching events. Like moving them to constructors.

Like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int _pIndex = 0;
    List<IItem> list = new List<IItem>();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        list[_pIndex].Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            _pIndex++;
            _pIndex %= list.Count;

            Next();
        };

    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        list = new List<IItem>()
        {
            new ItemImage() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Name = "Image1" },
            new ItemImage() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), Name = "Image2" },
            new ItemImage() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Name = "Image3" },
            new ItemImage() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7), Name = "Image4" }
        };
        Next();
    }

    void Next()
    {
        var tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = ((IItem)list[_pIndex]).Name;
        StackPanel1.Children.Add(tb);
        list[_pIndex].Show();
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Attaching event handlers in constructor works smoothly. Thanks a lot!